# PUT requests in rails don't update the status on respond_with calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Given the following controller in rails:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json, :xml
    def update
        @account = Account.where(uuid: params[:id]).first
        unless @account.nil?
            if @account.update_attributes params[:account]
                respond_with @account, location: account_url(@account)
            else
                respond_with error_hash, status: :unprocessable_entity, root: :error, location: api_account_url(@account)
            end
        else
            respond_with error_hash, status: :not_found, root: :error, location: accounts_url
        end
    end

    def error_hash
        { :example => "Example for this question", :parameter => 42 }
    end
end
```

I would expect a `PUT` request to /accounts/update/ to do the following

1. If the id exists, and the update_attributes call succeeds, deliver a `204 (No Content)` success message.  (I have it set to return @account, which would be nice, but no big deal.  204 is fine here.)
2. If the id exists, but the data is bad, deliver a `422 (Unprocessable Entity)` error message, along with the xml/json to represent the error.
3. If the id does not exist, deliver a `404 (Not Found)` error message, along with the xml/json to represent the error.

What actually happens is:

1. Deliver a 204 with no body.
2. Deliver a 204 with no body.
3. Deliver a 204 with no body.

Why is it that it ignores both my status and my body?  I've had a similar setup for `GET` requests that work out just fine (correct status, correct body).

Example `CURL` request (for an ID that does not exist):

`PUT` request

```
curl -i --header "Accept: application/xml" --header "Content-type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"name": "whoop"}' http://localhost:3000/api/accounts/3d2cc5d0653911e2aaadc82a14fffee9
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content 
Location: http://localhost:3000/api/accounts
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: bf0a02f452fbace65576aab6d2bd7c1e
X-Runtime: 0.029193
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2013-01-15)
Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2013 08:01:31 GMT
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: _bankshare_session=BAh7BkkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRkkiJWFmNmI2MmU0MzViMmE3N2YzMDIzOTdjMDJmZDhiMzEwBjsAVA%3D%3D--133e394eb760a7fce07f1fd51349dc46c2d51626; path=/; HttpOnly
```

`GET` request

```
curl -i --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:3000/api/accounts/3d2cc5d0653911e2aaadc82a14fffee9
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Ua-Compatible: IE=Edge
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: 9cc0d1cdfb27bb86a206cbc38cd75473
X-Runtime: 0.005118
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2013-01-15)
Date: Thu, 24 Jan 2013 08:19:45 GMT
Content-Length: 116
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"friendly-status":"not-found","status":404,"message":"No account with id '3d2cc5d0653911e2aaadc82a14fffee9' found"}
```

Comment: Did you try `respond_with error_hash, status: 404, ...` instead of the symbol representation of the status?

Comment: Have you checked that your `#update` action actually gets called? Try `raise "test"` on the line after `def update` and see if it raises an error.

Comment: I've tried both of these things.  I have a `logger.debug "Failed to update object with params #{params[:account} for id #{id}" and a `respond_with error_hash, status: 404` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: (as in, the method gets called, but I have the same result).

Comment: Interestingly enough, this looks to only be an issue with `respond_with`, it works just fine with `respond_to`.  I'm wondering if it's a bug, now.

Comment: I agree, I think it must be a bug.  There's no good reason for this behavior that I can think of.  For now I'm working around it using `render` instead of `respond_with` but it feels dirty.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0d3333257156544feba729ba28f6874d5a30d561) discussion this rather non intuitive behavior is due to the desire to maintain compatibility with the scaffold.

> In general we keep the responder the same implementation as the
> scaffold. This allows us to say: replace respond_to by respond_with
> and everything will work exactly the same.
>
> -- **josevalim**

You have two choices to override the default behavior.

#### A) Pass a block to respond_with

```
unless @account.nil?
  if @account.update_attributes params[:account]
    respond_with @account do |format|
      format.json { render json: @account.to_json, status: :ok }  
      format.xml  { render xml: @account.to_xml, status: :ok }
    end
  else
    respond_with error_hash do |format|
      format.json { render json: error_hash.to_json(root: :error), status: :unprocessable_entity }
      format.xml { render xml: error_hash.to_xml(root: :error), status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
else
  respond_with error_hash do |format|
    format.json { render json: error_hash.to_json(root: :error), status: :not_found }
    format.xml { render xml: error_hash.to_xml(root: :error), status: :not_found }
  end
end
```

It's unfortunate that we have to return to duplication for each format, but that seems to be the current recommendation up to Rails 4.0 so far; see [here](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActionController/Responder).

You should return **200 - OK**, not **204 - No Content** if you are returning the updated object, or don't return anything and have your client code 'GET' the updated object. :location is not meaningful in an api context, it's for redirecting an html response.

#### B) Create a custom responder

```
respond_with @account, status: :ok, responder: MyResponder
```

I've not done this myself so I can't give an example, but it seems like overkill here anyway.

Check out [Railscasts Episode:224](http://railscasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3) for some discussion of respond_with including custom responders.

Answer (score 3):

Did you see ActionController::Responder class ?
Here are some methods to think about

```
 # All other formats follow the procedure below. First we try to render a
    # template, if the template is not available, we verify if the resource
    # responds to :to_format and display it.
    #
    def to_format
      if get? || !has_errors? || response_overridden?
        default_render
      else
        display_errors
      end
    rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate => e
      api_behavior(e)
    end
```

and

```
def api_behavior(error)
      raise error unless resourceful?

      if get?
        display resource
      elsif post?
        display resource, :status => :created, :location => api_location
      else
        head :no_content
      end
    end
```

As you can see  api_behavior works for post and get methods but not for put .
If an existing resource is modified, either the 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) response codes SHOULD be sent to indicate successful completion of the request.

head :no_content is what you get.

So reason of this is that rails doesn't understand what are you trying to do. Rails thinks there is no error when you use  respond_with in this case.(it's not a bug  you just shouldn't use it that way)

I think `respond_to` is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, I would simply try this first. 
The `.first!` will make rails emit a 404 if the record is not found.
In case of success will render 204.
In case of error while saving it will extract errors from the model errors object.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :xml

  def update
    @account = Account.where(uuid: params[:id]).first!
    @account.update_attributes params[:account]
    respond_with @account, location: account_url(@account)
  end
end
```

If model validation messages are not enough, then you will need to conditionally emit the result.
The success path will work as above and in case of failure you will render what you need.

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json, :xml

  def update
    @account = Account.where(uuid: params[:id]).first!
    if @account.update_attributes params[:account]
      respond_with @account, location: account_url(@account)
    else
      respond_to error_hash do |format|
        format.json { render json: error_hash, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.xml { render xml: error_hash, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def error_hash
    { :example => "Example for this question", :parameter => 42 }
  end
end
```