# This controller's create action works fine, but the almost identical update is just returning 204 regardless

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
def create
    if request.headers['Auth'] == User.first.token
      @post = Post.create(post_params)
      @post.save
      respond_with(@post)
    else
      error =   { error:  'gotta be authed to create' }
      respond_with(error, :status => 401, location: nil)
    end
  end

 def update
    if false #request.headers['Auth'] == User.first.token
      @post.update_attributes(post_params)
      respond_with(@post)
    else
      error =   { error:  'gotta be authed to edit' }
      respond_with(error, :status => 401, location: nil)
    end
  end
```

[image]

## edit:

apparently this is considered a correct way to handle PUT by the rails team (I have no idea why)  can anyone give me some insight on how they handle respond_with actually behaving consistently?

See these issue/pullreqs to get a better idea of how rails considers this response correct
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9862
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9887

Comment: oops added wrong img, getting correct img one sec

edit: updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so apparently you just need to pass a block to respond_with if you want to customize it - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/18929275/1429856

My solution was to change

```
respond_with(error, :status => 401, location: nil)
```

to

```
  respond_with error do |format|
    format.json { render json: error, :status => 401, location: nil }
  end
```